# Child process to kill its parent whithout terminating itself

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I kill parent process script from child process script, without terminating child process in Linux.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, please.

Comment: *Why* would you ever want to do this? What's the use case?

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement), especially if you're trying to do some sort of daemonization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shell defines PPID, `kill $PPID` will kill the parent.  If your shell does not define `PPID`, you can probably get it with `PPID=$( ps -o ppid= $$ )`.  There is no reason for this action to kill the child.

Comment: The child should become the child of process 1 (`init`) when the parent is killed.

Comment: Rather do kill -9 $PPID to make sure parent process does gets killed. #JustAddingOn ;)

Comment: @Sylar Sending `SIGKILL` is always a bad idea.  If the process does not terminate cleanly in response to `SIGTERM`, that is a bug that needs to be fixed.  Using `SIGKILL` is a terrible hack.

Comment: Is it? Can you explain the bug a bit more? I would like to know if that's not the right thing to do!

Comment: @Sylar The bug is in the program receiving the `SIGTERM`.  Unfortunately, many such programs exist, but using `kill -9` should always be done with caution.  Many recommend at the very least doing: `kill pid; sleep 5; kill pid; sleep 5;  kill -9 pid` checking after each sleep that the process is indeed still alive.  See http://linuxfordummies.org/kill-9-why-you-should-not-use-it-unless-absolutely-necessary/

Comment: Oh. I knew the signal thing. Didn't know SIGKILL was untrappable. Thanks for the great link!